# Is there any way to play quicktime mov files on Vista X64 natively

Tags: windows, 64-bit

Does anyone know of a x64 directshow filter combination that is capable of playing MOV files in Vista X64 when Media Player is running in X64 mode?

I've tried so many its getting pretty frustrating. HAALI and MPC can split the thing but unfortunately only output audio, there is a vague possibility that quick time alternative will work.

Answer (score 4):

Quicktime alternative wouldn't work because it just uses the Apple Quicktime decoder but strips away the "goodies" installed with a regular install of Quicktime.

You're looking for a 64bit directshow filter which can decode Quicktime video, because Apple hasn't written/compiled a 64bit version, you'll have to look at other filters which can decode Qt. Mplayer/ffmpeg could but hasn't got a 64bit version and can not be used as a filter. But ffdshow which is an awesome decoder package does have a [64bit version](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=173941&package_id=199416&release_id=569930), depending on the version of Quicktime your trying to decode I think it would work.

If you're trying to decode HD quicktimes you would have to wait for the [CoreCodec AVC 2.0](http://forum.corecodec.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1126&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&sid=a6672343063f72e0ae58194a01081bc6&start=20) release which has a 64bit filter..

Answer (score 3):

I have had some success using [RiverPasts Quicktime Direct Show Filter](http://www.riverpast.com/en/prod/quicktime/) in Windows 7 x64. Unfortunately I cannot try it in Vista currently but it may solve your problem.

Comment: I tried RiverPast the filter with mixed luck. It is an x32 filter that seems to be doing some dirty tricks to get itself to work on x64 (for example x64 GraphEdit does not show it), I was sort of able to get it to work once, but now I can not get it to work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Will the [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/about_kl.htm) do what you want? It has 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Only thing is I'm not sure if you can playback the MOV within Windows Media Player, it might have to be Media Player Classic (that comes with the pack).

Comment: Tried it, no luck in native x64, klite x64 is pretty tight, though it does not ship with the codec debugging thingy yet

Answer (score 0):

I've used this QuickTime DirectShow filter in the past and it allows Windows Media Player to playback all QuickTime fileformats natively.

http://www.medialooks.com/products/directshow_filters/quicktime_filter.html

Comment: Media looks seems to be the only filter that consistently works, apart from the ugly medialooks logo that is finding its way on all the videos, the problem being it only works on x32 ...